# unable to find mpd.conf file

Tags: mpi, mpich

I have installed MPICH2 1.4 version on RHEL.
Whenever I'm trying to run a program then it is throwing following error

unable to find mpd.conf file

How to resolve this problem.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes from running an old version of MPICH that requires some setup. You might try upgrading to a much newer version (the latest is 3.0.4) available at http://www.mpich.org and you don't have to worry about setting up MPD because it will use the newer process manager (Hydra) by default.

Comment: What setup is required?

Comment: I'm really not sure what's required to make that work. Is there a reason you can't upgrade to the newest version?

Comment: I can upgrade it to new version. But the problem is I have done benchmarking by using MPICH2 1.4 version. Now they are asking me to do with the same version.

Comment: Is there any chance you can do both benchmarks with the most recent version (3.0.4)? If you're looking for performance, you're almost always going to get better results with a more recent version.